# Timestamps in Conemu?

Tags: conemu

For example, League of Legends chat is like this:

[image]

For each line, there is a timestamp next to it. Can we make Conemu like that?

Comment: That's going to be a shell or command prompt setting, not a Conemu setting.

Comment: @Herb How do I do that?

Comment: That's going to depend on which shell you're using.